# Facebook Sharing with angular JS variable replacement

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to share my web page and I am using angular js variables in order to pass the meta tag values. For image, I am using it like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{imageUrlStr}}">
```

And for title:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}">
```

But when I try to share it, facebook share popup displays this like {{title}} and the image is not visible.

When I inspect the statement  over Chrome, I can see that all the variables are injected.

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: Facebook does not process JS in this way - you'll need to server side render those pages with node.js

Comment: How about if I put the facebook codes right after angular js variable injection? Is it possible that it works?

Comment: You can't change the Open Graph meta tags with JavaScript after the pageload, as Facebook requests the page from the server again when looking for the meta tags, and so it will not find the updated tags. Facebook also only searches the header for the Open Graph meta tags, so adding them in the body will not work either.

Comment: How about if I run the facebook javascripts right after angular js rendering? I have had a look at the render callback for angular js. There is not a formal solution func for it there are ways to do it with directives.

Comment: _“How about if I run the facebook javascripts right after angular js rendering?”_ – that won’t change anything either. The Facebook scraper, that requests your page to read the OG meta data, has nothing to do with the FB JS SDK. _Again:_ You need to make your server respond with the OG meta tags embedded into the HTML source code directly. That is the only thing the FB scraper looks at. No Angular, no JavaScript, no wishful thinking.